# A game based on the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

The following game is based on a somewhat "stupid" version of the Euclidean algorithm (where we allow only subtractions).

Positions are given by finite non-empty multisets (repeated elements allowed) of strictly positive integers.

An allowed move picks two elements $a\geq b$ in the multiset
and replaces the larger element $a$ by the difference $a-b$
if $a>b$, respectively removes one of the two (identical) elements
from the multiset if $a=b$.

Both player have the same moves and the first player which
cannot move (which happens if and only if the multiset is
reduced to a singleton defining the gcd of all numbers in the initial multiset) loses.

Is there an infinite subset $\mathcal S$ of $\mathbb N$ such that  the second player has a winning strategy on all non-empty finite subsets of $\mathcal S$?
(Distinct powers of $2$ looked very good to my computer:
The second player has a winning strategy for all non-empty subsets of $\{1,2,4,8,16,32\}$. The game has however first-player winning
strategies for some subsets of powers of $2$ involving $64$,
e.g. $\{1,2,8,16,64\}$.)

Final remark: The standard Conway theory can be applied but seems a bit useless: The number of possible moves gets large for large multisets.